# How can we customize the default commit message used by the fetch extension?

Tags: mercurial, fetch, hgrc

The default commit message that fetch uses, "Automated merge with ...." is long, ugly and litters the history with local directory paths. I'd like to replace it with a simple "Automated merge" or just "Merge".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default the message is not customizable (check out "library.zip" under your Mercurial install folder, you'll see the message in plain text under `hgext\fetch.pyc`).

So the only way is to update source code of "fetch" - try [**this version**](http://codepad.org/EKVNTiK4), I just changed the message to "Fetch merge" and it works like a blast :)

You'd need to remove `library.zip\hgext\fetch.pyc` and put there `fetch.py` (plain python file) with the content from the link above.

Comment: Excellent - those commit messages were bugging me, too.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using a custom built fetch extension like suggested earlier, you can also overwrite the comment message using an alias:

```
[alias]
fetch = fetch -m "automated merge"
```

Just put the above code into your local .hgrc (mercurial.ini on Windows).

Comment: fetch seems [deprecated](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/fetch). is there an alternative to the `fetch -m` command ?